# How to get a JavaScript Variable value in multiple text box in a jsp page on select a listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a list box which is populating data from the database.Now i have to implement a functionality that will store that list box value in a variable and show it in a text box using id.I am able to pick that value and can store it in a text box,but the problem is that i want that value in multiple text box .That functionality is not working ,i am posting here what i have done so far,

```
   var myvalue=$("option:selected",this).text();
   document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=myvalue;


   <div style='display:none;' id='business'>    

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="lebelMergin" for="_Name">
                <span class="spanMergin">Name</span>
                <input type='text' class='text' name='business' id="hiddenField" />                 
                </label>

             </div>  

            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="lebelMergin" for="_email">
                <input type='text' class='text' name='business' id="hiddenField" />
                </label>
            </div>


    </div>
```

what i am doing here i am using the hiddenField to get that generated value ,but that is not coming in the second textfield.Somebody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code.use of same id more then one time not work. give class name to all text box 
and asign value

```
 var secondvar ;
 var myvalue=$("option:selected",this).text();
 $('.text').val(myvalue);
  secondvar = my value;
```

```
        <div class="form-control">
            <label class="lebelMergin" for="_Name">
            <span class="spanMergin">Name</span>
            <input type='text' class='text' name='business' id="hiddenField" />                 
            </label>

         </div>  

        <div class="form-control">
            <label class="lebelMergin" for="_email">
            <input type='text' class='text' name='business' id="hiddenField" />
            </label>
        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: yes it is working..thanks a lot but can i get that value in a variable and use in the place of Name??

Comment: cant understand . please explain . if you feel my answer help you pls up vote or mark answer.

Comment: i want that value in a jstl variable

Comment: as i knw not possible to assing javascript variable value to JSTL variable. not only JSTL with other language also.

Comment: can i use the  hiddenField as a variable

Comment: you can set value on hidden field using javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65869/discussion-between-lucifer-and-nishit-maheta).

Comment: chat server is not work at my office. its blocked. on my answer there is one up arrow symbol then 0 then down symbol. you can up vote there

Comment: can you help me in setting that javascript variable in other variable which i can use further??

Comment: You need to set same value in hidden field

Comment: Take hidden field with same class name . it will auto set  value in hidden field